# Error to compile this contract

Tags: erc-20

The contract is

```
[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"supply","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"}]
```

The error is
C:\xampp\htdocs\smart_contract>solcjs --abi token.sol
token.sol:1:1: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interf
ace/library definition.
 ... [ ...

How could import the directive to avoid the error?

Answer (score 1):

This is no contract, that's the ABI of a contract. It cannot be compiled, as that's a "byproduct" of a compilation. I highly recommend not doing these things manually, but to use the truffle framework. As you stated in your other question, you already found the truffle boilerplates (e.g. truffle unbox webpack), just give them a run with a sandbox ethereum net (ganache) and start modifying what you have, till you get where you need to be.

Comment: help me here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/55854/trying-to-compile-with-truffle-show-vbs-error